# GWT style code splitting in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, gwt

I do a lot of work with GWT but don't have experience of Flex. I was talking to a guy today who was looking at moving some large Flex based applications to GWT due to the Flex application getting too big and using too much memory in the browser. This is a problem I have had before with GWT - browser apps using lots of memory as all the code gets loaded when it starts.

However, in GWT 2.0 there is now a code splitting feature to overcome the problem of the client code getting too big. This allows all the code (javascript) not to be loaded as one big file on start up but instead code split into different files that can be loaded when required.

I was thinking as to if there is anything similar in Flex. I assume the Flex application code all lives in one single SWF file which loads at start-up so this approach is not possible but thought there might be other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [Modules](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/modules/Module.html). Otherwise the code is in one SWF. You can also move the [Flex framework code out of yur SWF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flash_player_cache_04.html). And you can always dynamically load your resources such as images.